# PCA in a 3D torch

Tags: visualization, pytorch, pca

I have a 3D tensor. The rows are different dialogues. The columns utterances `(1,...,n)` from the dialogue and the cell the `embedding` of the utterance (text).

```
tensor.shape = (100, 88, 512)
```

**100 dialogues, 88 utterances each dialogue, 512 embedding dize.**

I want to see if the utterances from the same column are related by projecting them using, for instance, PCA. I.e, for instance, if the utterances from the same column are in the same area in space (when compared to the others)

How can I apply PCA in a tensor 3d?

Answer (score 1):

Each dialogue is a 88 X 512 matrix which can be viewed as a 88*512-length vector. You can apply PCA on the 100 X (88*512) matrix you would get.